# Check select Change After Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

Hy everyone I searched a lot for a solution but I don't find any suggestion, thanks for your help ;)

My problem is that I have 2 or 3 selects within a form like that:

```html
<select name="type" id="type">
  <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($id);$i++){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id[$i] ?>"><?php echo $nom[$i] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>

<div id="largeurHolder">
  <select name='largeur' id='largeur'>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($largeur);$i++){ ?>
     <option value='<?php echo $largeur[$i] ?>'><?php echo $largeur[$i] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="hauteurHolder">
  <select name='hauteur' id='hauteur'>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($hauteur);$i++){ ?>
     <option value='<?php echo $hauteur[$i] ?>'><?php echo $hauteur[$i] ?></option>
    <?php }?>
  </select>
</div>
```

SO I want to change #largeur value relatively to #type and #hauteur value relatively to #type with ajax, my ajax is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#type").on('change',function(){
  var type = $('#type').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'check.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {type:type,act:'type'},
      success:function(data){
        $('#largeurHolder').show();
        $('#largeurHolder').html(data);
      }
  
    });
    $('#hauteurHolder').html('<select disabled="disabled"></select>');
 return false;
  });
  
  $("#largeur").on('change',function(){
 alert('koko');
    var type = $('#type').val();
 var largeur = $('#largeur').val();
 $('#hauteurHolder').hide();
 $.ajax({
   url: 'check.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {type:type,largeur:largeur,act:'largeur'},
    success:function(data){
   $('#hauteurHolder').show();
   $('#hauteurHolder').html(data);
    }
 }); 
  
  });
 return false;
});
```

About the script check.php it return values like that:

```html
<?php
if($_POST['act']=='type'): //------------TYPE ACTION
  list($largeur) = GetALlLargeursFromPneus($db,$_POST['type']);
  echo '<select name="largeur" id="largeur">';
  echo '<option value="">Choisissez</option>';
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($largeur);$i++)
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$largeur[$i].'">'.$largeur[$i].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
   
  elseif($_POST['act']=='largeur'): //------------LARGEUR ACTION
    list($hauteur) = GetALlHauteursFromPneus($db,$_POST['type'],$_POST['largeur']);
    echo '<select name="hauteur" id="hauteur">';
 echo '<option value="">Choisissez</option>';
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($hauteur);$i++)
 {
   echo '<option value="'.$hauteur[$i].'">'.$hauteur[$i].'</option>';
    }
   echo '</select>';
  endif;
?>
```

The problem is that when I change #type all works fine but when I would to change #largeur after Ajax call it don't work.

Note that when I change #largeur without changing #type is work fine, So i think that my problem is after ajax call.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you getting the alert value "koko" when you change the #largeur after changing the #type ??

Comment: No I did not get it. anyway I resolved the issue :D it was in my PHP script I removed echo '<select name="largeur" id="largeur">'; Thank you for your response ;)